# Why are unrelated divs overlapping when they aren't in a common div?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, the first one is a banner, and the second one a wrapper with cards in it:

```
<div class="banner" style="z-index:-1 ;background: url(<%= asset_path "bg#{num}.jpeg" %>;">
  <div class="banner-content">
    <%= link_to("Publier", new_post_path , :class => "btn btn-transparent btn-lg") %>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #F4F4F4;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= render "shared/card" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= render "shared/card" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= render "shared/card" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= render "shared/card" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= render "shared/card" %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only CSS I've added is this:

```
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

They are overlapping. 
Shouldn't they be displayed one below another ? Why are they overlapping here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `absolute` positioning for the first `div`. Remove `position:absolute;` from banner.